# Passing integer as string in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am parsing an xml file which has one table as below:

```
<table name="categoryAttributeTable">
    <row>
        <field name="CID">201</field>
        <field name="name">page_title</field>
        <field name="value">Spotlight</field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="CID">301</field>
        <field name="name">page_title</field>
        <field name="value">Oryx highlights</field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="CID">501</field>
        <field name="name">page_title</field>
        <field name="value">Little Taster</field>
    </row>
</table>
```

I want to search value of CID 301 for which the ans should be Oryx highlights but i am getting Spotlight as ans which is the value of CID 201. Why this might be happening???
My java code is :

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("/home/media.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :"+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("table");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        String titlevalue=null;
        String cidvalue=null;
        String lidvalue=null;
        List a = new ArrayList();
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("categoryAttributeTable"))
                {
                    NodeList nList1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("row");

                    for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < nList1.getLength(); temp1++) {
                        Node nNode1 = nList1.item(temp1);
                        if (nNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode1;
                     NodeList nList2 = eElement1.getElementsByTagName("field");
                     for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nList2.getLength(); temp2++) {

                         Node nNode2 = nList2.item(temp2);
                         if (nNode2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                             Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode2;
                             if(eElement2.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("value"))
                             {
                                titlevalue=eElement2.getTextContent();
                               // System.out.println(" Title value :: "+titlevalue);
                             }
                             if(eElement2.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("CID") && (eElement2.getTextContent().equals(String.valueOf(301))))
                             {
                                 System.out.println(" Title value :: "+titlevalue);

                             }
                         }
                     }
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In `eElement2.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase()` if i pass string then the output is coming as expected but if i pass integer as string then it is showing previous level's ans.
Please help me...

Comment: I'm not really clear as to what exactly happens. "If I pass Integer as String" ... this makes no sense. Whether a String looks like "six" or "6", this should not make any difference, unless you made a mistake somewhere handling it.

Comment: I want to say that eElement2.getTextContent().equals(""). This parameter accepts string value. so when i pass any string inside it then it gives proper values . but i want to pass integer inside that so i passed String.valueOf(201) but it is showing value of previous row.

Comment: Now did u get my question

Comment: Any decent equals method takes an Object as parameter,  so, both String and Integer should work. My point is, you say that it works if you pass a String, but it doesn't work when you pass a String. So no, I don't really see what you mean, either it works or it doesn't.
Just like String.valueOf("301") as you have in your code doesn't make sense. Why are you turing a String into a String? It Already is one.
Have you debugged the code?

Comment: dude ...just change the order of your xml ....like this <row>
  <field name="value">Oryx highlights</field>
  <field name="CID">301</field>
  <field name="name">page_title</field>
 
 </row>

Comment: m not allowed to change an xml file

Comment: ok wait ... will deal it diffrently

Comment: Yes pls share your thoughts if u find something

Comment: ok tell me ... the values CID, will they be different or they can be repeated ?? i.e CID tag values are 301,401,501...will they come again(301) in further CID tags

Answer (score 0):

See this...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadXMLFile {public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("src/test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :"+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("table");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        String titlevalue=null;
        String cidvalue=null;
        String lidvalue=null;
  List<String> valueList=new ArrayList<String>();
  List<String> cidList=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("categoryAttributeTable"))
                {
                    NodeList nList1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("row");

                    for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < nList1.getLength(); temp1++) {
                        Node nNode1 = nList1.item(temp1);
                        if (nNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode1;
                     NodeList nList2 = eElement1.getElementsByTagName("field");
                     for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nList2.getLength(); temp2++) {

                         Node nNode2 = nList2.item(temp2);
                         if (nNode2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                             Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode2;
                              String value1=null;
                              String value2=null;


                             if(eElement2.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("value"))
                             {
                                 valueList.add(eElement2.getTextContent());
                             //   System.out.println(" Title value :: "+eElement2.getTextContent());
                             }

                             if(eElement2.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("CID") && !(eElement2.getTextContent().equals("NULL")))
                             {
                              //   System.out.println(" XXXXXXXXXXX Title value :: "+eElement2.getTextContent());

                                cidList.add(eElement2.getTextContent());

                             }
                         }
                     }
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<valueList.size();i++)
        {

            System.out.println("value :: "+ valueList.get(i)+" corresponding cid :: "+ cidList.get(i));
            //System.out.println("cid :: "+ cidList.get(i));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out where your mistake is. This is your original code.

```
if (nNode2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
   Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode2;
   if(eElement2.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("value")){
       titlevalue=eElement2.getTextContent();
   }
   if(eElement2.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("CID") && (eElement2.getTextContent().equals(String.valueOf(301)))) {
       System.out.println(" Title value :: "+titlevalue);
   }
}
```

---

```
<row>
    <field name="CID">201</field>
    <field name="name">page_title</field>
    <field name="value">Spotlight</field>
</row>
<row>
    <field name="CID">301</field>
    <field name="name">page_title</field>
    <field name="value">Oryx highlights</field>
</row>
```

The order of the values of name attribute are `CID`, `name` and `value`. In the end of first loop of `row` tag, you will set `titlevalue` = Spotlight. Then in the beginning of second loop of `row` tag, you will skip the first `if` as the first field attribute is equal to `CID`. But the program will enter the second `if` because you define `name=CID` and the `content=301`, hence it displays `titlevalue` = Spotlight.

Try this.

```
Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode1;
NodeList nList2 = eElement1.getElementsByTagName("field");

for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nList2.getLength(); temp2++) {
    Node nNode2 = nList2.item(temp2);

    if (nNode2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode2;
        String nameattr = eElement2.getAttribute("name");

        if (nameattr.equalsIgnoreCase("CID")) {
            titlevalue = eElement2.getTextContent();

            // If CID != 301, skip the whole loop.          
            if (!titlevalue.equalsIgnoreCase("301")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (nameattr.equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {
            System.out.println("value: " + eElement2.getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
```